# Resolve $() variable

Tags: continuous-integration, workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

I'm working on a migration of a Continuous Integration project from TFS 2008 with .proj file and Powershell scripts to TFS 2012 with Workflow Foundation and I have a problem with the interpretation by WF of variables who start with $() like $(solutionDir), $(buildDir), ... Which are very used in TFS configuration and in TFS 2008 scripts.

Every time, I try to use a variable like them as a variable or argument to avoid hard-coded paths and print the result with a WriteBuildMessage activity, I’ve got a string with the unresolved variable instead of the wanted path.

I try call ExpendEnvironnementVariable activity, toString method, assign to a different variable but nothing.

How to get the full path result of these variables in Workflow Template or code activity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the WF environment variables to your activity

```
BuildDirectory="[BuildDirectory]"
```

and then read them as an InArgument in your workflow code

```
public InArgument<String> BuildDirectory { get; set; }
```